# What does 1 inside eval body mean in perl?

Tags: perl

What does 1 inside the eval block in perl mean?
see the sample code:

```
eval { 
    print "Ajay";
    1;
} or do { 
    #handle Error Gracefully 
}
```

Do we tell perl runtime that there was no error that we encountered in the eval block by specifying some positive value at the end of the block?

Or Is it mandatory to specify something at the end?

Answer (score 4):

The two syntactic constructions `eval BLOCK` and `do BLOCK` do *almost* the same thing: both execute their block and return the result of the most recently evaluated expression from that block. The difference is that `do` might not return at all, whereas `eval` will always do so.

The reason `do` might not return is that the code its block is executing might `die`. That "throws an exception" (not an error, but an exception) that teleports your execution way up the stack to the first dynamically enclosing exception handler.

In contrast, if in the course of executing the `eval`, the code within it "dies" (read: some exception occurs) rather than itself dying, the `eval` immediately returns `undef` and sets the global `$@` variable to the exception that made it die.

So that `1;` at the end of your `eval` block guarantees that it returns 1 no matter whether the `print` statement itself does so. The `print` operator returns 1 on success and 0 on error, setting the global `$!` variable to contain the error. It does not `die`. So if the `print` failed, then without that `1;` the `eval` itself would appear to have failed if you're only checking it for true or false the way the logical operators like `or` do.

There is no reason to do this, because `print` does not throw exceptions.